# How to install untrusted packages?

Tags: package-management

I tried to install Skype on Ubuntu 10.04 and I received the following error:

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages 
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
Details : 
gcc-4.6-base:i386 libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libffi6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 liblcms1:i386 libmng1:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libuuid1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will lead you further [click here for detailed information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)

Mind you: I've never tested this solution, since I don't use Skype. But it should work according to the Wiki

Succes !

Answer (score 0):

To install skype from trusted place:

If you are using 64 bit, you have to enable multiarch

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add the repo of skype

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

Update your sources list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install skype from command line

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Now, To install untrusted packages you can do it from command line not from GUI like Ubuntu Software Center.

You'll be prompted whether you wanna install from untrusted choose yes